# Return object by reference in c++

Tags: c++, reference, stl, return-by-reference

To optimize, I am returning objects by reference since, I do not need to change them,
and they can be really large objects. But what if, in case, the underlying object is not present?

Example, consider below code...

```
map<string,map<string,int> > mMap; 

map<string,int> &  GetReference(string x){
    if(mMap.find(x)==mMap.end()){

    }else{
        return mMap[x];
    }
}

int main()
{
    mMap["abc"].insert(make_pair("cat",1));
    mMap["abc"].insert(make_pair("dog",2));

    map<string,int>& temp = GetReference("abc");
    map<string,int>& temp2 = GetReference("def");

    return 0;
}
```

Here, temp2 will be an error. So what can be done here?

Comment: Depends what you want to achieve. It could be reasonable to insert missing elements, or to throw an exception, or to suffer undefined behaviour.

Comment: It depends.   How do you expect your program to behave if an error occurs?   For example, does subsequent code ASSUME that `temp` and `temp2` are correctly initialised?   Do you want to check if an error has occurred before proceeding under the assumption that `temp` and `temp2` are correctly initialised?

Comment: Yes it does @acraig5075, thanks a lot.

Comment: You can return a pointer instead of a reference. A null pointer is a perfect sentinel.

Comment: Like I can modify the subsequent code, depending on its implementation. But, I think using a pointer here is the best option I have, otherwise I have to insert empty objects... (to return reference to the empty object)

Comment: Exactly! @Evg , thanks a lot